# Postfix not recieving mail from Gmail

Tags: postfix, email-server, gmail

I've Installed Postfix with Dovecot on CentOS 7. Everything is working good when I try to send / recieve emails from services like Outlook.. etc.

However, there is a problem when I send an email from my account on Gmail to my email on my server. The messages never get to my server, instead, they are delivered back and that's the reason mentioned in the message:

```
Technical details of temporary failure:
Google tried to deliver your message, but it was rejected by the server for the recipient domain xxxxxxxx.com by xxxxxxxx.com. [xx.zz.186.133].

The error that the other server returned was:
454 4.7.0 TLS not available due to local problem
```

Here is my `main.cf` file: http://pastebin.com/3Di4PYxt

Here are the files in the `/etc/postfix` folder:

```
access                 header_checks.inbound.db     ldap       transport
canonical              header_checks.internal       main.cf    transport.db
generic                header_checks.internal.db    master.cf  virtual
header_checks          header_checks.submission     relocated
header_checks.inbound  header_checks.submission.db  ssl
```

I have those files inside /etc/postfix/ssl:

```
server.crt  server.csr  server.key  server.key.secure
```

I followed this tutorial to Install the mail server: http://www.krizna.com/centos/setup-mail-server-centos-7/

Note: I've seen [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/653664/cant-receive-mails-from-gmail) question and it didn't help.

Comment: I had the same problem, in my case it was a problem with the certificates. If I remember correctly the certificate didn't match the key or something like that (I forgot to update all files after renewing certificates).

Comment: On second though, it was the filesystem permissions in my case. run `ls -l /etc/postfix/ssl` and check if postfix is allowed to read the key file.

Comment: The answer to so many of these kinds of questions is in the application's log files. I've always found Postfix's logs to be clear and helpful in diagnosing problems.

Comment: I don't what is the problem with the people who just love to down vote, I've been getting down votes for no reason since I entered this website, it's not a real helpful community if you just down vote me and pass away. Talking about the problem: There is nothing in the log files and there shouldn't be, the messages are not delivered my Gmail so I have nothing to look here.

Comment: As you haven't shown neither logs nor the current configuration, we couldn't really help you except of guessing.

Comment: I've posted the current configuration already, and I've said that I've checked the log files and there was nothing on it. If you didn't know the answer, it doesn't mean that you should down vote the question. Elsewhere,most questions would be down voted. The good thing is, I've found the answer myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I've managed to solve the problem using this link: https://workaround.org/ispmail/squeeze/ssl-certificates

Had to run those commands (as root):

```
mkdir /etc/ssl/private/

openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -nodes -out /etc/ssl/certs/dovecot.pem -keyout /etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem

chmod o= /etc/ssl/private/dovecot.pem

openssl req -new -x509 -days 3650 -nodes -out /etc/ssl/certs/postfix.pem -keyout /etc/ssl/private/postfix.pem

chmod o= /etc/ssl/private/postfix.pem

postconf -e smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/postfix.pem

postconf -e smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/postfix.pem

service dovecot restart

service postfix restart
```